# mysql query to find id fulfilling condition on several rows

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a mysql table with the following columns:

```
id_entry    
id_player   
id_achievement
claimed
```

and need to find all players that have claimed specific **id_achievement** (in my example 46, 53 and 63) and have claimed it (**claimed** = 1).

I've tried several things, the closest one being:

```
$this->db->select('id_player');
$this->db->from('user_achievements'); 
$this->db->where_in('id_achievement', ['53','46','63']);
$this->db->where('claimed', 1);
```

But it will return the **id_player** if any on the three achievement is complete (I need all of them).
What would be the best way to do this?
(I am using Codeigniter's Active Record)

Comment: try where instead of where_in

Comment: it gives a syntax error. It seems you can't have an array when using where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you're running multiple commands independently. try something like this:

```
select id_player, count(*) from
(select id_player, id_achievement
from user_achievements
where id_achievement in (53, 46, 63)
and claimed = 1
group by id_player, id_achievement) sbqry
group by id_player
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: That still returns all of them

Comment: I misread the question. Adjusted my answer.. Now you're running a subquery that groups by player and achievent but only shows results for the three selected achievements. Then you run a grouped statement on that and use a having statement to filter for the ones that have all three

Comment: It's getting closer I think. The exact query you suggested doesn't return anything. If I only take the subquery it returns 39 id_player's, some of them once, some twice and some thrice. I tried to replace "having count(*) = 3;" by "having count(*) != 9999" to test the outcome and I get id_player = 1 and count(*) = 39, which is strange

Comment: i forgot the second group statement... thats what happens when you type queries blind without testing. anyway adjusted it now.

The subquery will give you one row for every achievement per player. Then you group this output again by only id_player to get the number of rows (achievemtns per player). that is why you want `having count(*) = 3` of the grouped statement - this way it will only show the players who have all three achievements